# How can I use SSH remotes with GitHub Desktop?

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I am using GitHub Desktop on Windows 10. I initially cloned a repo using its HTTPS URL, but now our organisation have advised that we must use the SSH URL instead. So I have changed this over.

I have also copied the contents of my public SSH key (`id_rsa.pub`) in to my GitHub account. My SSH key is protected by a passphrase.

Now when I try to do to a sync in GitHub Desktop I get the following error:

[image]

In Git Bash it works fine (it asks me for my passphrase before each pull/push though). Any idea what I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Is there something missing to my answer below?

Comment: I have changed my answer, to include one using an OpenSSH one: can you check if this is better?

Answer (score 11):

As more recently seen in "[Permission failure cloning in Git in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61546958/6309)", try and launch GitHub Desktop after:
(**warning**: read [comments first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993115/how-can-i-use-ssh-remotes-with-github-desktop/62102606?noredirect=1#comment114208668_62102606))

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe'"
```

That will ensure GitHub Desktop to use the right OpenSSH `ssh.exe`, instead of an internal one, as seen in [`desktop/desktop` issue 5641](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5641).

**If Git bash does not work properly** after that, you can either:

- revert the configuration:

  ```
  git config --global --unset core.sshCommand
  ```
- or use the [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) SSH

  ```
  git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe'"
  ```

If `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\` is already in your `%PATH%`, you don't even need that configuration: the `ssh.exe` from Git For Windows would be the one selected by default.

Comment: Does not work for me. Before this, at least git bash was working.

Comment: @DarkMath OK, what version of Windows and of Git are you using? And you can cancel that with `git config --global unset core.sshCommand`

Comment: **Don't do this, it will make your Git bash stop working, at least that's what happened to me.** I should have read @DarkMath comment... smh

Comment: @RaphaelSetin But you should be able to revert it easily enough: `git config --global --unset core.sshCommand`

Comment: @RaphaelSetin I have edited the answer to include a clearer warning on the unintended consequences of that `git config` option.

Comment: I figured a way to revert it, but thank you for adding it there; it will help others for sure if this happens to them too

Answer (score 4):

solved the problem by unticking the system OpenSSH setting.

[image]

Comment: wouldn't this just disable ssh?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working by creating an ssh config file with the content similar to what is provided in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/JoaquimLey/e6049a12c8fd2923611802384cd2fb4a

The minimal content I needed to get it working was

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_github
```

When cloning the repository I had to use the URL option because the Github.com tab will use the HTTPS url.

Answer (score 2):

After searching and trying to use ssh-agent unsuccessfully, I found if you start github desktop using a git bash shell, it will prompt you for a passphrase. I added an alias to my .bash_profile to make starting github desktop easy.

`eval C:/Users/labrat/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/GitHubDesktop.exe`

I also have my git core.sshCommand set to this, which works for both git bash and github desktop:

```
git config core.sshCommand "'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\ssh.exe' -i C:/Home/.ssh/id_rsa_name"
```

Comment: Where did you find .bash_profile file on Windows 10?

Comment: should id_rsa_name be my private or public? I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue now as well. SSH was working fine in git-bash with ssh-agent and so forth.

But if you use TortoiseGit, for me the easiest was to use TortoiseGitPlink.exe globally as ssh-client, from TortoiseGit, git-bash and github desktop:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe'"
```

This will by default use Pageant to cache your passphrase for current session. After setting this, GitHub Desktop immediately started working again with ssh repos.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but was related to my Docker container ssh keys weren't in my windows .ssh/ folder.

%userprofile%.ssh/