# Permission failure cloning in Git in Windows

Tags: git

When I clone from GitHub using CMD or PowerShell with ssh-agent on Windows 10 v.1909, the following shows:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

However, I ran `ssh -vT git@github.com` and the key does work

```
debug1: Offering public key: {My key}
```

And

```
Hi {My username}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But with Git bash I can clone just fine.

This also happen with GitLab.

I tried

```
Host *
 ForwardAgent yes
```

in `.ssh/config` and it doesn't work.

I also tried every solution from [GitHub Support Page](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey) and [GitHub Community Forum](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Git-via-SSH-from-Windows-returns-Permission-Denied/m-p/9336) and still doesn't work.

PS. I prefer Windows cmd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Powershell session, try:

```
$env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'; git clone git@gitlab.com:myuser/myrepo.git
```

And see where SSH is looking for your default id_rsa/id_rsa.pub key pair.

Make sure, if the private key is passphrase-protected, to [launch ssh-agent first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153372/6309).

The OP mentions:

> Apparently, Git doesn't use native OpenSSH.

That is false. Maybe [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) does not use OpenSSH, as seen in [desktop/desktop issue  5641](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5641): "Desktop does not use OpenSSH on Windows if running, favours embedded SSH"

Hence the workaround:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe'"
```

But Git itself does:

```
D:\prgs\gits\current\bin>where ssh
D:\prgs\gits\current\usr\bin\ssh.exe

D:\prgs\gits\current\bin>ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

This is more recent than the Windows one:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

(Winver: 1909, build 18363.836=

That is why I always launch tools with my [own PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624681/6309)

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

That way, I am sure I will use Git tools first (incuding an OpenSSH one) before anything else.

Comment: This is default ssh key ```C:\\Users\\%username%/.ssh/id_rsa``` However ```ssh -vT git@github.com``` offer ssh-agent key ```Offering public key: RSA SHA256: [SHA] [External directory]``` no need to type passphase. But ```git clone``` doesn't.

Comment: If I put SSH in ```C:\\Users\\%username%/.ssh/id_rsa``` I have to type passphase every time I use ```git``` command. Which is annoying.

Comment: I think that using ``git``` command doesn't offer ssh-agent key but with ```ssh``` only ssh-agent does offer.

Comment: @buratud git has nothing to do with ssh-agent. If your SSH private key is passphrase-protected, only ssh-agent (launched separately) is able to provide said passphrase.

Comment: but why git doesn't trigger ssh-agent than, it's weird. Same SSH but different behavier.

Comment: I give up, using linux can get rid of this.

Comment: @buratud That will work indeed. But git alone is not concerned with SSH. Which is why git does not trigger anything SSH-related.

Comment: @VonC the original line requires a `;` between setting the env var and calling git clone.

Comment: @Robin Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that git doesn't use native OpenSSH. Here what's I did

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe'"
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5641#issuecomment-421801704)