# Git SSH issue: Terminal works fine, but all GUI clients fail

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, permission-denied, public-key

So, I'm having this issue with git & Github where things work as expected when I use the terminal however tying to do anything from Git GUI Clients like the GitHub desktop app, SourceTree, Fork gives me the  *Permission denied (publickey)* issue.

Even trying out commands like `ssh -T git@github.com` in the terminal, works as expected. Here's a screenshot of my Github Account settings from Fork: As you can see, it looks like even my SSH key has been configured correctly & seems to be recognized. I want to avoid the process of generating a new SSH key and setting it up in GitHub unless there's literally no other option.

[image]

Comment: Did you `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`?

Comment: To fix this we'll need to know what OS you're using, what ssh (e.g. on Windows, could be native ssh or putty/plink or something else), and how your ssh key is configured (does it have a password, have you set up ssh-agent?)

Comment: I'm on mac, I'm using ssh-agent with a passphrase.

Comment: @DavidWest I have edited the answer to include MacOS.

Comment: Is your private key added as an identifier for the Mac user?

Answer (score 2):

> Even trying out commands like ssh -T git@github.com in the terminal, works as expected.

Double-check the SSH URL used for your remote repository in those GUI clients.

It should be `git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>`.

As, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62102606/6309), try first, before launching GitHub Desktop:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe'"
```

(assuming Windows 10 here)

For Mac, follow "[How to Manage Multiple SSH Keys](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-manage-multiple-ssh-keys/)" and make sure your key is added to the ssh-agent:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/_id_rsa
```

with a `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
```

> SSH will look for key in keychain and if it finds it you will not be prompted for password.
>   Key will also be added to ssh-agent. On MacOS this will work on MacOS Sierra 10.12.2 or later.